# Flex: Karaoke app out of sync on playback,after publishing on an external server

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, synchronization, delay, wowza

I'm trying to create a Karaoke app in my spare time, but i'm having some problem syncing the recording and the backing track.

Basically, after i start to publish to an external media server (wowza), when i play back with the recording (mp3, ripped from the recording flv) and the backing track (mp3 too), i notice a delay of 0-800 ms between the 2 track, which is a big time for this type of application.
This delay is always random, as bigger in windows than macs.

I already tried many solution, amongs the others:

- Playback with the Sound.extract method, taking 2048 samples each time, to have less latency for the audio start/processing;
- Set the microphone silence level to 0;
- Sync by cuepoint, in different cases in flv or in the mp3 (extending the sound class)

But every time, i get mixed results (worse results in windows, best results in mac)

Anyone has some suggestion to give? Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: have you solbved your problem ?